# Symfony Joining Related Records

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new to Symfony and going through the book on Symfony website and to be exact [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#joining-related-records) section.

In the first example the following function is used to join the two tables `product` and `category` and it is making perfect sense

```
public function findOneByIdJoinedToCategory($id)
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p, c FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Product p
            JOIN p.category c
            WHERE p.id = :id'
        )->setParameter('id', $id);

    try {
        return $query->getSingleResult();
    } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

What I dont understand is the second example,

```
public function showAction($id)
{
    $product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')
        ->findOneByIdJoinedToCategory($id);

    $category = $product->getCategory();
}
```

When in first function two tables are being joined then what is the purpose of `$category = $product->getCategory();` in second function?

The problem I have with this code `$category = $product->getCategory();` is if i leave it as it is it works fine **IF** the product has any assigned category, but if the product does not have any assigned category i get the error

`Call to a member function getCategory() on a non-object`

If i remove the code `$category = $product->getCategory();` and access the product where no category is assigned then I get the error that i should `404`

I will really appreciate if someone can explain to me why is this happening.

Comment: I can say there is no point of both `p` and `c` in select while the entities are bidirectional joined. What I would recommend is checking if the `$product` is not empty, because if it could not find any record or it found more than one record `getSingleResult` will throw an exception and the function will return `null`; base on that you the errors comes up.

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering why use this code `$category = $product->getCategory();` when the the `join` is already fetching the category

Comment: Because the function returns a product.  How else do you expect to get the category?  The point of using a query to join the category is to avoid lazy loading which requires an extra sql statement when you want the category.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad for the explanation, I am trying to understand the concept, if i dont use the `$category = $product->getCategory();` I can still access the category name via {{ product.category.name }} that is what is puzzling me.

Comment: The question is not why the second function exist, I undetstand why it exist I just wanted to understand why use `$category = $product->getCategory();` when we already have access to category name via the join

Comment: Under the hood, {{ product.category.name }} is just a twig shortcut for $product->getCategory()->getName().Try: $product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')->find($id).  It works the same as your query except it will kick off an extra sql query when you access the category.  The toolbar will let you see the queries.

Comment: Just to be clear, $category->$product->getCategory() was not needed.  Just something the authors decided to add in there.  The non-object error you were getting was because you requested a product that did not exist.

Comment: Thanks @cerad thats what I thought too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line  $category = $product->getCategory(); is useless if you don't need this variable $category. 
if you didn't JOIN in the query this line $category = $product->getCategory(); will make another query to database to get the Category.

As for the twig {{product.category.name}} if there was no JOIN and no relation it will, the category will be null, it is not related to $category = $product->getCategory(); code.